# SQL database: search more than one column

Tags: c#, sql, database, sqlite, search

I got this code which works fine:

```
DataView dv = new DataView(bazaDataSet.tbl_baza);

if (listBox1.SelectedIndex == 0)     
{
     dv.RowFilter = string.Format("Name LIKE '%{0}%'", txtSearchData.Text);
     dataGridView1.DataSource = dv;
}
```

but I'm trying to search more than one column, and I can't get it to work for me. At the end I want user to be allowed to choose more then one item from listBox and search database regarding that choice.

Comment: `Column1 like '%a%' or Column2 like '%a%' ...` ?

Comment: Thank You Ivan, works perfectly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can build up strings that can be used in your `RowFilter`, something like

```
dv.RowFilter = string.Format("Name LIKE '%{0}%' AND City LIKE '%{1}%'", txtSearchData.Text, txtSearchDataCity.Text)
```

You would have to iterate through the search terms that your user selects though so in the case of a `listBox` you could do something like this building up a string as you go

```
StringBuilder rowFilter = new StringBuilder();

foreach (var item in listBox1.SelectedItems)
{
    if(rowFilter.Length > 0)
    {
        rowFilter.Append(" or ");
        rowFilter.Append("Name LIKE '%" + item.ToString() "%'");
    }
}
```

Then for your `RowFilter`

```
dv.RowFilter = rowFilter;
```

This link may help as well - [DataView RowFilter Syntax](http://erison.blogspot.co.uk/2010/03/dataview-rowfilter-syntax-c.html)

Comment: Thanks on detail description, yours and Ivan's recommendation worked perfectly!

Comment: As the answer worked perfectly, would you mind accepting it as the answer please?